# xQuery and Saxon. For each value of the parameter a new tag

Tags: xquery, saxon

I got the following sample xml:

```
<meci>
  <nodes>
    <node id="x">
      <mlfbs>
        <region value="H">
          <mlfblist>
            <mlfb partno="1" masternode="false" />
            <mlfb partno="2" masternode="false" />
          </mlfblist>
        </region>
      </mlfbs>
    </node>
  </nodes>
</meci
```

And I have written the following xQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0";
<ProductList>
{     
  for $a in /meci/nodes/node
  return
   <Product>
     <id>{data($a/@id)}</id>
     <mflb>{data($a/mlfbs/region/mlfblist/mlfb/@partno)}</mflb>
   </Product>
}
</ProductList>
```

The result looks like

```
<ProductList>
  <Product>
    <id>x</id>
    <mflb>1 2</mflb>
  </Product>
</ProductList>
```

But I'd like to get the following result:

```
<ProductList>
  <Product>
    <id>x</id>
    <mflb>1</mflb>
    <mflb>2</mflb>
  </Product>
</ProductList>
```

Could anyone please tell what I am doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated, I have been search hours with no solution :/.

Cheers
stefan

Answer (score 1):

Use one more `for` to get `mflb` list:

```
<ProductList>
{     
  for $a in /meci/nodes/node
  return
   <Product>
     <id>{data($a/@id)}</id>
     {for $mlfb in data($a/mlfbs/region/mlfblist/mlfb/@partno)
     return <mflb>{$mlfb}</mflb>}
   </Product>
}
</ProductList>
```